# Notepad++ Search and Replace regex: Extracting information between brackets across multiple lines then return its output to its original format

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm struggling with a Regex in Notepad++. I need to extract all information between sets of brackets in a large .txt file from eQuest, deleting the rest. The text and integers within the brackets span across multiple lines. Lastly, I've been trying to print the data within the brackets on its own line.

Here's a snip of the data:

```
"EL1 Bldg Occup WD" = DAY-SCHEDULE_PD
    TYPE            = FRACTION
    VALUES          = [ 0, &D, &D, &D, 0, 0, 0.15, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1, 0.85, 0.75, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
 ..
"EL1 Bldg Occup WEH" = DAY-SCHEDULE-PD
    TYPE             = FRACTION
    VALUES           = [ 0, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, 0.1, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, 
     &D, &D, 0 ]
..
"EL1 Bldg InsLt WD" = DAY-SCHEDULE-PD
    TYPE             = FRACTION
    VALUES           = [ 0.1, &D, &D, &D, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 0.85, 0.95, &D, 
     &D, &D, &D, &D, 0.8971, 0.8709, 0.6, 0.6, 0.3, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 
     0.15 ]
..
"EL1 Bldg InsLt Sat" = DAY-SCHEDULE-PD
    TYPE             = FRACTION
    VALUES           = [ 0.15, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, 0.3, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, 
     &D, &D, 0.15 ]
..
"EL1 Bldg InsLt Sun" = DAY-SCHEDULE-PD
     TYPE             = FRACTION
     VALUES           = [ 0.15 ]
..
"EL1 Bldg InsLt HDD" = DAY-SCHEDULE-PD
     TYPE             = FRACTION
     VALUES           = [ 0 ]
..
"EL1 Bldg Misc WD" = DAY-SCHEDULE-PD
     TYPE             = FRACTION
     VALUES           = [ 0.2, &D, &D, &D, 0.2118, 0.3452, 0.7395, 0.8743, 
     0.8977, 0.9, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, 0.8385, 0.5067, 0.3161, 
     0.2517, 0.2075, 0.2 ]
..
"EL1 Bldg Misc Sat" = DAY-SCHEDULE-PD
     TYPE             = FRACTION
     VALUES           = [ 0.2 ]
..
```

The Output I am looking for is as follows:

```
 0, &D, &D, &D, 0, 0, 0.15, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1, 0.85, 0.75, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0 
 0, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, 0.1, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, 0 
 0.1, &D, &D, &D, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 0.85, 0.95, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, 0.8971, 0.8709, 0.6, 0.6, 0.3, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15 
 0.15, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, 0.3, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, 0.15 
 0.15 
 0 
 0.2, &D, &D, &D, 0.2118, 0.3452, 0.7395, 0.8743, 0.8977, 0.9, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, 0.8385, 0.5067, 0.3161, 0.2517, 0.2075, 0.2 
 0.2
```

Thanks!

Comment: "Notepad++" or "NoteBook++"?

Comment: Notepad++, thanks for the correction- edited the title.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind running a few regexes across the data set, then it should be fairly simple. I can't think of a way you can run a single regex to get the exact output you're trying to achieve.

*Regex 1*

```
   Find what: ^.+?(\[[^\]]+\])?$
Replace with: $1
```

*Regex 2*

```
   Find what: (\r?\n)+
Replace with: \r\n
```

*Regex 3*

```
   Find what: ,\s*\r\n\s*
Replace with: ,
```

**NOTE:** The replace with has a space at the end. So, it's ", ".

*Regex 4*

```
   Find what: ^\[\s([^\]]+)\s\]
Replace with: $1
```

*Output from multiple regexes*

```
0, &D, &D, &D, 0, 0, 0.15, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1, 0.85, 0.75, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, 0.1, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D,&D, &D, 0
0.1, &D, &D, &D, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 0.85, 0.95, &D,&D, &D, &D, &D, 0.8971, 0.8709, 0.6, 0.6, 0.3, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15,0.15
0.15, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, 0.3, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D,&D, &D, 0.15
0.15
0
0.2, &D, &D, &D, 0.2118, 0.3452, 0.7395, 0.8743,0.8977, 0.9, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, &D, 0.8385, 0.5067, 0.3161,0.2517, 0.2075, 0.2
0.2
```

Comment: If you don't mind a challenge, would it be possible to reverse this process-  I'm running an analysis and edit on the output from the multiple Regrexes and returning it in the same format as the output. How would I run a find and replace Regrex into the exact format from the original data? I'm struggling with keeping the same data format...in order for eQuest to read the file again with replaced data, it has to keep the same line break constraints from the original data snip I posted.

Comment: Yep, I enjoy challenges. I'm assuming that you will need to find/replace the 
"VALUES" field of the particular "EL1 Bldg" element. This would require more information to be stored on the output format. It sounds like there's potential for duplicate values, and you will be modifying the values during your analysis. Which means your output would be completely different than the field you are wanting to replace. So, at this point I would write code that could parse the format and rebuild the string. There's a few ways to approach this, but it depends on your business rules for the best approach.

Comment: If we could limit problem with business rules, then it's potentially feasible to do with a regex. However, I'd need to see how you can tell that line x goes with element y. I'm assuming this would be done based on line number, which is why the parser would be the better/easier approach at this point.

Comment: Yes, I would be replacing the "values" field back in the order they came with my edited value sets. There is potential for duplicate values in that different title elements could have the same value outputs as other title elements. To my understanding, the only way to know which value field goes with what title is the order in which they are presented. Lastly, my value sets are surrounded by () instead of [] above, which is how the file is read by Equest. And the "value" lines are limited to 79 characters before they move to the next line. lmk if you need the actual file to see whats happening